# extending vectors to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: vector-spaces

We know, the following vectors form a basis of $\mathbb R ^4$

$$
B:=\{(1,2,3,4)^T, (2,0,1,-1)^T, (-1,0,0,1)^T, (0,2,3,0)^T\}
$$

It's easy to proof that, we only need to show these vectors are linear independent and show that these 4 vectors generate $\mathbb R^4$

But I don't know how to extend $\{(0,4,5,9)^T,(3,3,3,3)^T\}$ with some vectors of $B$ also to a basis of $\mathbb R^4$ ? I guess I must proof the given two vectors are linear independent and now ? try and error !?

Thomas

Comment: You could try finding a vector that is not in the span of $\{(0,4,5,9)^T, (3,3,3,3)^T\}$, let's call this vector $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$. Then repeat this process, i.e., try finding a vector which is not in the span of $\{(0,4,5,9)^T, (3,3,3,3)^T, (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)\}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, trial and error. There aren't that many options to try. Since the second vector in the incomplete basis has constant entries, you can see immediately that you won't be able to change the order of the entries of the first one using the second (except by completely reversing it), so $(2,0,1,-1)^T$ is linearly independent from these two. Then just try the other three vectors of $B$ until you find one that's linearly independent from these three.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to see why $(2,0,1,-1)^T$ is linearly independent from the other two !? Of course I can figure it out but how to see ?

Comment: @fast-forward: It would help if you explained what part of my argument for its linear independence you don't understand.

Comment: I understand why the two incomplete vectors must be linearly independent, but I don't know how this implies that $(2,0,1,-1)^T$ must be linearly independent from these two.

Comment: @fast-forward: That wasn't my question. My question was which part of my argument for its linear independence you don't understand. I'm referring to this argument: "Since the second vector in the incomplete basis has constant entries, you can see immediately that you won't be able to change the order of the entries of the first one using the second (except by completely reversing it)". Rather than me rephrasing the argument into the blue, it would help if you explained why you don't find it convincing.

Comment: Sorry, maybe i overlooked something, but for me the only explanation is why the given two incomplete vectors are independent. Unfortunately, I don't know why exactly the vectors you are chosen must be independent from the given two. I don't see any reasoning in the form of: $(2,0,-1,1)^T$ must be linearly independent because of ...

Comment: @fast-forward: The formulations "$X$, so $(2,0,1,-1)^T$ is linearly independent" and "$(2,0,1,-1)^T$ must be linearly independent because of $X$" are synonymous.

Comment: now it seems to be logical. i can use every vector as the third, which is not a multiple of the first simply because of the constant vector. your explanation was correct. simply a misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

for linear independence it is good that you consider first and second coordinate Zero in each two vector for example A=(0,0,x_1,x_2) and B=(0,0,y_1,y_2);this will help you that in linear combination $c_1(0,4,5,9)^T+c_2(3,3,3,3)^T+c_3 A^{T}+c_4 B^{T}=0$ you catch $C_1 $ and $C_2$ equal zero.it will be remain that you determine $x_1 ,x_2$and$y_1$ $y_2$ such that you catch $c_3$and $c_4$ equal zero too.

with attention that $c_1$and $c_2$ are equal zero at this condition $(A=(0,0,x_1,x_2) ,B=(0,0,y_1,y_2))$
it will be enough that you have $c_3(0,0,x_1,x_2)+c_4(0,0,y_1,y_2)=0$ obviously the best choice will be $x_1=1,x_2=0$ and $y_1=0,y_2=1$